# How to parse USER-AGENT field in http header using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to parse some information from the `User-Agent:` HTTP header. The problem is that I'm getting two `User-Agent:` HTTP headers in the same HTTP Request:

```
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (http://iim.com/a.jph) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
```

I want the regex to match the non-http portion e.g **Windows NT 6.1; WOW64**. The flow analyzer software I'm using java regex engine.

**My attempts**

User-Agent:\s+.*?((.*?))

Its matching both; I want to skip http portion of it.

Comment: Why do you want a regex when a string function is 10x faster in a case like this?

Comment: I cannot use string function its not programmable im using closed source solution.

Comment: Reg expressions are not universal.  This sounds like a Stackoverflow question.  I would post the criteria then post what you have tried.  The syntax required to do this is simple but every programming language has its own way of doing something like this.

Comment: @Ramhound I have updated the question.

Comment: @Ramhound its java engine ; no version mentioned as far I know.

Comment: Java 6, Java 7, something else entirely?  This could make a difference in the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *several* problems with this question:

- You haven't told us what programming language you are using, or at least which flavor of regular expressions. POSIX? PCRE? Something unusual?
- In what context are you using this? Are you running an HTTP server, and clients are submitting requests like these? Or are you running a proxy that is accepting these requests and analyzing them? Which proxy are you using -- is it something you've written by hand (in what language?) or something you downloaded?
- It's not clear from your post that you're getting two `User-Agent:` headers specified in a single request. In your post, you seem to have some line break problems (which I've edited), but it appears that you are getting three *separate* HTTP requests, and it's perfectly okay to have different `User-Agent:` in each HTTP request. If you are actually getting input from a client like the data you were seeing in your original post (with NO linebreak after the `User-Agent:` and before the next `CONNECT`), then someone is trying to fool your proxy on purpose by omitting the linebreak, and attempting to do HTTP pipelining through your proxy. A standards-compliant implementation will have linebreaks, even if the HTTP Request Body is empty.
- Trying to parse things using regular expressions is dangerous. At the very least, you need to be prepared to handle arbitrary input. There is no universally agreed-upon standard for the formatting of the `User-Agent:` string, and many public Internet hosts that connect to a public web server will attempt to "fuzz" the server by sending it malformed requests. It is perfectly possible for a client to submit headers such as the following, even all in a single request if they want:

  User-Agent: Lol your regex won't match this
  User-Agent: Mozzarella/0.-0 ((Let's )()confuse your reg((ex))((()) ApplePie/-NaN (FUZZ, like Police) 3.14159\EvilAttacker )
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows LOL 973.1; LOL64) ...
- Trying to understand a client's user-agent and then glean useful information from that is *stupid*. Because the client can set it to whatever they like, you should not consider a given user-agent to *mean* anything at all. It's like if I tell you "I have a million dollars!" -- do you have any particular reason to believe me? I'm simply *alleging* that fact. `User-Agent:` is no different. A Windows 95 box could allege to be Windows 8.1 running IE 11. A Mac OS X 10.8 box could allege to be Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 running Firefox 2.0. Someone deliberately trying to fool with you could allege that their operating system is "AsadzOS version 0.1".

There are very few reasonable uses of the `User-Agent:` header, and in each of those use cases, it is essential that you handle all possible matching failures, false positive, false negatives, etc. very carefully, and prevent any unintended behavior in your parser by giving up if you can't make sense of the input.

On top of *all this*, this is a question for StackOverflow, as it is completely off-topic on SuperUser to be discussing programming techniques. I just needed to post this long-form answer to explain to you why this is a bad question.

Comment: It feel like you have overstated or over explained a very simple question,and not a bad question, I have submitted multiple time questions regarding regex and I got excellent help. I mentioned in my question , that these packets, payloads or header information I'm getting is from flow analyzer box. Its closed source. I don't have api interface to program it, I can just write regex which are using java engine at backend. I don't why overstretch it so much.:O

Comment: I'm NOT writing a white paper ; infact for every single point you mentioned i can write 100 or 1000 lines of counter argument why i need the regex and things about user-agent tampering is not applicable to my use-case; but then thats another fight that I can do on emails or chat.

Comment: If you have access to a "flow analyzer" box (presumably a tap into raw ethernet or IP packets for a large network), why are you asking for such a simple regex? Try using [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/). Learn the concepts behind regular expressions, and you won't have to ask a question every time you need to develop a regular expression. Furthermore, this question is *still* bad, because you didn't even give us a regex you **tried** to write to capture the OS information from the `User-Agent:`. I'd be more inclined to help if you gave a non-working regex and explain how it fails.

Comment: @Ramhound neither Have i written more then 10 lines comment for any regex question I have ever posted on this site; but then I have been lucky also as others have not stretched every single details to atomic levels.

Comment: @asadz - This question requires more then 10 lines to explain. I can't judge your previous questions because I have not seen them, and if they were as poorly explained as this one, you don't want me to go voting on those questions.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah and that number is dependent upon person skill set or level of understanding? right.

Comment: @asadz - What?  Multiple people want to know what you have tried yourself in order to get a better understand of what you have already tried.

Comment: @Ramhound multiple ; i said neither NOT a single one for this question; in simple terms it just meant wants to A in text and skip B; who needs explanation about user-agent benefits or negatives? Did i asked this. Did anyone even tried to put the syntax or poor try on regex even?

Comment: @asadz I have the solution and will post it provided you post your attempts.  It's not perfect for the same reasons allquixotic brought up but something more then nothing

Comment: @Ramhound my requirement is not to go for perfect but for the best fit? Ok I will try.